# Repeating the Puppeteer code (a process) more than once

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Ok, so let's say I have this code that is currently working great:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch;
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(timeout);
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 1000 });
  await page.goto(`https://www.website1.com`);

  // Grab the result
  while (true) {
    const result = await grabResult(page);
    console.log(result);


 //Do something with the above data in website2.

await page.goto(`https://www.website2.com/`);

await page.waitForTimeout(5000);    

  }

})();
```

I want to add a line, so that I could repeat the same process (above code) more than once.

And have some kind of option to set the process repeat count.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a variant:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  let counter = 10;

  while (counter--) {
    await page.goto(url);
    // Other code;

    await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: hey vsemozhebuty, actually I already have all of this in my code. Basically, I'm just looking a line of code (if it exists) that would repeat the whole process x times. Where's x, I could set how many times. So, let's say you would want to repeat your above code 10 times. Is there a command for that?

Comment: The simplest way is a loop with a counter. See an example in the edited answer.

Comment: It did worked for a simple code. thanks. However, my code contains `while` also, so I guess there is some conflict with your `while (counter--)`. Can you look into my updated question and suggest a solution.  I'm not a coder, but I think there can't be `while` in a `while`.

Comment: You can have `while` in `while` if the inner `while` has a condition to exit from the inner loop. You have a `while (true)` loop (perpetual loop) — has it a condition to exit or do you just abort the whole script?

Comment: Right now I just abort it. Close the CMD. But I guess I can add an exit (you mean `await browser.close();` just like in your code?) Initially, I just thought of running an infinite loop, until I abort it. As for my code, so you are saying that my `true` in a `while()` triggers a command to loop everything that's in that `while (true)`? That's probably why I'm getting errors related to that in my Terminal and why your `while` doesn't work with my code. I actually don't need to loop what's inside my `while (true)`. So probably I just need to get rid of the true and add the close?

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand your situation completely. Maybe it is worth describing your task in the question generally. Otherwise, we may have [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) :)

Comment: I agree, sorry for that. I guess I'm starting to understand what you are saying. Thanks for the explanation regarding the `while (true)` loop (perpetual loop). I think this is where the problem lies. I think I know how to fix it.

Comment: Good luck and ask another question if you have any difficulty)

Comment: Got it to work! Removed the `while (true) {}` which was leftover from the previous code. Thanks a lot for your help vsemozhebuty.